# reverse display of div and div completely overlaps another div

Tags: html, overlap

I can not change HTML that's given below, only CSS can be changed.

Also "mcontainer"  has variable height.

HTML IS:

```
<div id="contentcontainer">
    <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="mcontainer" class="container"></div>
</div>
```

```
#contentcontainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

#mcontainer { /*To make it appear on the top*/
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100% !important;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

mcontainer completely overlaps sidebar

I want that sidebar should be displayed below mcontainer

How is it possible?

Comment: _"I want that sidebar should be displayed below mcontainer"_. So get rid of the positioning and put the sidebar div after the mcontainer div. Side note, you forgot to close your inner div tags.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but I can not change the HTML... only css can be changed.....

Answer (score 0):

You have seriously learnt a lot of positioning I guess. It's a total mess.

Basically [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/K2SWN/) what you want:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="contentcontainer">
    <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">2</div>
    <div id="mcontainer" class="container">3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#contentcontainer {
    position: relative;    
    background:#ddd;
}

#mcontainer { /*To make it appear on the top*/    
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}

#sidebar {    
    position: absolute;
    top:30px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but its not working... as and when I add more content in "#mcontainer".... it overlaps "#sidebar"... as already mentioned "mcontainer" has a variable height